# Directory.EnumerateFiles returns no files in case of multiple extensions

Tags: c#, file-io, system.io.directory

I have a problem which I cannot handle with.

When I use EnumerateFiles it returns no files, where I know there should be over 3k results.

My code looks like here:

```
private IEnumerable<string> TestGetFiles(string path, params string[] exts)
    {
        var extsAsWildcards = exts.Select(x => "*." + x).ToArray();
        return exts.Select(x => "*." + x) .SelectMany(x => Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, x));

    }
```

I took this code from here: [Git link](https://gist.github.com/zaus/7454021#file-linqpad_ext-cs)

None of solutions work and I need this solution for multiple extensions. The only method worked for me is this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetCurrentFontFiles(string item)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(item + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, "*.ttf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
        return files;
    }
```

Which works, but only for single extension.

Please help me guys, I dont want to use GetFiles which is extremly slow (I have over 10k files in folder).

**EDIT1**
I call method with this filter:

```
string[] extensions = {"png"};
```

**EDIT2**

My example to reproduce:

```
    private IEnumerable<string> TestGetFiles(string path, params string[] exts)
    {
        return exts.Select(x => "*." + x).SelectMany(x => Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, x));
    }
    private List<FileSizeList> GetPNGFiles(string pathForFiles)
    {
        List<FileSizeList> PNGFiles = new List<FileSizeList>();

        string[] extensions = {"png"};
        IEnumerable<string> files = TestGetFiles(pathForFiles, extensions);
        foreach (var file in files)
        { //no iteration here

        }
    }
```

**EDIT3 Working solution**

I know where was the problem. I modified a code and added missing SearchOption

```
private IEnumerable<string> TestGetFiles(string path, params string[] exts)
{
    var extensions = exts
       .Select(x => x.StartsWith(".") ? x : "." + x)
       .ToArray();
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(fn => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fn), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: Maybe `exts` already contains the `.`. You should show an example. How many extensions do you filter?

Comment: There's not really such a thing as "multiple extensions", but I think you mean files with a dot in their filename (without extension), like `foo.bar.txt`? Or do you mean you want to enumerate all `*.txt` and all `*.jpg` files? Can you show some example filenames and example input to this method?

Comment: Might I suggest having less than 10k files in a folder to begin with?

Comment: If you just mean you want e.g. *.jpg and *.gif, then if the second version works for one specific extension, and the first version shows how to combine the results of multiple calls to `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, what happens if you combine the two?

Comment: Thank you for replies. 
I call method with this: string[] extensions = {"png"}; so there is not dots in extension

Comment: This code works for me. Is this your actual code, or do you actually call `return extsAsWildcards.Select(...)`, adding the `*.` twice? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: This is my actual code.

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is slow because you are searching this folder that contains 10k files multiple times (for every extension). Instead you can use this:

```
private IEnumerable<string> TestGetFiles(string path, params string[] exts)
{
    var extensions  = exts
       .Select(x => x.StartsWith(".") ? x : "." + x)
       .ToArray();
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path ,SearchOption.AllDirectories)            
       . Where(fn => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fn), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Obviously you also want to search subdirectories. Then use `AllDirectories`.

As MicroVirus has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439200/directory-enumeratefiles-returns-no-files-in-case-of-multiple-extensions/33439380?noredirect=1#comment54667540_33439380) it was case-sensitive. Now it is case-insensitive. So it doesn't matter if the extension is `png` or `PNG`. Maybe that was causing your issue.

Comment: When call it it returns: Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"
The problem not it is slow. The problem is it doesnt return anything

Comment: OP's problem is "this code doesn't work" and "**GetFiles** [..] is extremly slow ". This is not OP's actual code.

Comment: if files are inside another directory add `SearchOption.AllDirectories` like the one worked for you maybe thats the problem ? @user1750355

Comment: @CodeCaster: If `GetFiles` is extremly slow also `EnumerableFiles` is extremly slow because they both need to search this huge folder multiple times to find files with the desired extensions. Another possible reason why OP's code could fail is if he passes extensions that already contain `.` (f.e. returned by `IO.Path.GetExtension`). That's fixed with `StartsWith`. If it still doesn't work(what seems to be the case) it's difficult to help because it _should_ work.

Comment: My extensions doesnt contains dots. Please look on EDIT1

Comment: @user please create an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.Select(x => x.StartsWith(".") ? x : "." + x)`? Also, there are issues when upper/lower case is mixed.

Comment: I added Edit2 with my example

Comment: @MicroVirus: you're right, was a copy-paste issue. Fixed

Comment: I mean matching "pic001.JPEG" from `EnumerateFiles` to the "jpeg" extension in `exts`.

Comment: @MicroVirus: yes, nice catch. Fixed